# Calculate Average Sum of values over a time interval in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of flow rates for multiple sensors and I want to report on the average flow rate at 5-minute intervals across all sensors for the last 24hr's. So far I have:

```
SELECT SUM(total_rate) as 'rate'
FROM sensor_stats WHERE `timestamp` > now() - interval 24 hour
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV 300
```

```
rate
10375130
7161878
22444777
11157688
28045465
```

This gets me part way but now I need the average value in each interval. The use case is trying to find out when flow rates are at their highest during a given day. I plan on displaying the 5 minute intervals on a graph.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is

```
SELECT SUM(total_rate) / COUNT(*) as 'rate'
FROM sensor_stats WHERE `timestamp` > now() - interval 24 hour
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV 300
```

or simply

```
SELECT AVG(total_rate) as 'rate'
FROM sensor_stats WHERE `timestamp` > now() - interval 24 hour
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV 300
```